# how Group by works on multiple columns

Tags: sql-server, group-by

I know what `group by x` clause in sql is, but now bit confused how it really works when we do `group by` on multiple columns.

i had thought `group by x, y` is almost similar to `group by y, x` but recently i noticed that both are not exactly same.

`select * from .... group by ID, State` resulted as below,

```
ID      State     TimeSpent
50001    ACW          2868
50001    AUX          9398
50001    Avail        3148
50005    ACW          1346
50005    AUX          1379
50005    Avail        2572
```

and `select * from .... group by State, ID` gave me output as below.

```
ID    State     TimeSpent
50001    ACW        2868
50005    ACW        1346
50001    AUX        9398
50005    AUX        1379
50001    Avail      3148
50005    Avail      2572
```

by looking at both the outputs can make-out that group by happens on very first column (i.e. col mentioned soon after `group by` clause) or is my understanding wrong?, please help me to know this better. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It will group on columns sequence like when you go for group by x, y then it will groups all records on x value then generate sub groups y

Comment: Your results are THE SAME, you should order them in the same order and you'll see it

Answer (score 0):

It will group on columns sequence.

[image: Please look at this image]

Comment: i suspected same looking into output pattern as i had mentioned in my post, but i don't think this will be always true.

Comment: Why do you think like this ?  What exactly did you not understand?